# How to hide a fr:tab in Orbeon 4.10?

Tags: tabs, orbeon, xforms

Currently using the `<fr:tabbable>` tag to create tabs in a form. 
However, when I try to make a tab relevant by referring to an individual node then it does not work. That is, the tab is visible all the time and not getting hidden if the referring node is hidden.

However, changing the `<fr:tabbable>` to `<fr:tabview>` worked straight away.

Here is my `fr:tab`:

```
<fr:tab id="history-tab" ref="//MY_NUMBER_FIELD">
```

When running the form if MY_NUMBER_FIELD is relevant then the tab should appear otherwise not.

Does `<fr:tabbable>` support hiding of tabs? or should I use a different attribute to achieve this effect? I have already tried the *'bind' and 'visible'* attributes.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `<fr:tabbable>`, you can use the `visible` attribute on `<fr:tab>`. The value of this attribute is taken as an XPath expression, expected to evaluation to a boolean.

Comment: As a side note, we should document `<fr:tabbable>`, and I've added a +1 from you on [issue 2390](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2390).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I set the tabs back to '<fr:tabbable>' and then set the tab to '<fr:tab id="history-tab" visible="false()">' but the tab is still visible. I tried other boolean xpath expressions but no effect on visibility. Maybe I have missed something obvious?

Comment: That attribute is only supported since Orbeon Forms 2016.1.

Comment: It would appear that it is time to upgrade. Thanks guys.